# Overloading the input operator to determine what kind of derived class to make?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, overloading

I have a base class called Animal.h

In there I have pure virtual methods that describe the noise an animal makes which is overwritten by derived classes (e.g. Cat/Dog) (which are in their own header files).

I have a main class to call functions and print out different things related to these classes.

I'm trying to overload the input operator in my Animal.h class to let me read in an input and create Animal classes based on whatever's been entered.

E.g. (In my main):

```
Animal *a = (animal*) 0;
while (read_animal(cin, a) && a)
    cout << *a << ’\n’;
```

In my Animal.h:

```
friend istream &operator >>( istream &input, animal* &animal_type )
{
    string in;
    getline(input, in);

    if (in.find("Cat") != std::string::npos)
    {
        *animal_type = new Cat();
    }
    return input;
}
```

But intellisense is telling me:

Error   3   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Cat'

Any ideas?

Comment: It should be `animal_type = new Cat();` and I don't see how you're getting a syntax error in this code.

Comment: Did you `#include` Cat.h? And is the class called `Cat`, not `cat`?

Comment: As Pawel has hinted C++ is case sensitive. Animal and animal are not the same thing.

Comment: Same error if I get rid of the *. Also no the Cat.h isn't included but I thought it doesn't need to be?

Comment: It totally does if you're using it...

Comment: A base class should not know it's derived classes, this is not a proper Object Oriented design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original Problem:

> Error 3 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Cat'

Your compiler does not know what a Cat is.
Have you included the appropriate header file.

But I would not do that.

Your operation is dependent on pointers. Which means you are passing pointers around without ownership semantics. Which leads to all sorts of issues. If you need to dynamically create different types I would have a management type that knows how to create different types of a specific class.

I would create a factory (this describes the relationship above (but there are other techniques)) that reads the type of first. Then creates an appropriate object and initializes it with a stream.

```
class AnimalFactory
{
    public:
        static std::unique_ptr<Animal> deserializeAnimal(std::istream& str)
        {
              // 1 Detect the correct animal type.
              str ????

              // 2 Create the correct object.              
              std::unique_ptr<Animal>  result(new XXXX); // or constructor takes a stream?
                                     // how you decide XXXX depends a lot on other parts of
                                     // the system.

              // 3 use the input operator to initialize it.
              str >> (*result);      // unless you already did this with the constructor.

              return result;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular dependency. You can't define the `Cat` class until its base class `Animal` is defined, and your definition of `Animal::operator>>` depends on `Cat`.

You'll need to split your `operator>>` into two parts, a declaration in the header file and a source that contains the body. In the source you can include the headers that define both `Animal` and `Cat`.